# Possibilities of accelerating EM algortihm

Tags: estimation, mathematical-statistics, algorithms, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to use the EM to estimate some parameters. I've programmed and it delivers. The problem however is that for each run of my programme, it can take either 5 seconds, 1min, 3min or more to give an estimate. So, I'm looking to accelerate the EM algorithm on the internet and I've find myself swamped with methods. There are so many - like Aitken's method, Louis', generalized conjugate approach, generalized gradient, hybrid methods like the ones based on Newton-Raphson, the ECM, and the ECME... (probably still missing some) - that I do not know which one to choose, and I simply do not have the time to study all of them by myself.
Hence, I ask for your help in deciding which one I should study.

I'm sampling from $ Y_n \sim \pi N(\theta_1+\theta_0Y_{n-1},\sigma^2)+(1-\pi)N(\theta_2+\theta_0Y_{n-1},\sigma^2)$ and I'm using the EM to estimate $\theta_1,\theta_2,\sigma,\pi$